# How do I get the console to update currently playing song?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a mpmediaitem which prints out the currently playing song, artist, album, but when the song changes the text does not change. Instead I want another label to be added when the song changes. How would I go about doing this?

```
var musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
let nowPlaying = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer().nowPlayingItem
let Title = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String
let Artist = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] as? String
let Album = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] as? String
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "getNowPlayingItem", name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()


}

  deinit{
    musicPlayer.endGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func getNowPlayingItem() {
    if let nowPlaying = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem {
        let title = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String
        let artist = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] as? String
        let album = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] as? String
        println("Song: \(title)")
        println("Artist: \(artist)")
        println("Album: \(album)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use notification center observer to monitor playing item change. Use Swift naming conventions (don't name variables starting from the capital letter). Use non-string casting to avoid exceptions if some data would be returned nil.

```
import MediaPlayer

lazy var musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "getNowPlayingItem", name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
}

deinit {
    musicPlayer.endGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func getNowPlayingItem() {
    if let nowPlaying = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem {
        let title = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String
        let artist = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] as? String
        let album = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] as? String
        let duration = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] as? NSNumber
        println("Song: \(title)")
        println("Artist: \(artist)")
        println("Album: \(album)")
    }
}
```

**UPDATED EXAMPLE**

Comment: When the song changes the new song information is not added to the console.

Comment: How would I add the artist, title, and album to a array? when I do `var items = [artist! + "\n" + title! + "\n" + album!]` they are not recognized since it's not globally instantiated, but if I globally instantiate it the NSNotification does not work. @rshev